# Referencing a UICollectionViewCell which is out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView with two cells. Each cell fits the size of the screen.
In the first cell I have some buttons.
When I tap a button, the collectionView scrolls to the second cell and depending on which button I tapped, the second cell should show a different view.

This code is to reference the second cell when I tap on a button:

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: secondIndexPath) as? SecondCell {

        // change the view of the cell
         print("Does not execute code")
}
```

I guess cellForItem(at: IndexPath) is nil because the cell is out of bounds.
But how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: secondIndexPath)
```

returns `nil` when the cell at the specified `secondIndexPath`isn't visible , you need to alter the model , and it will be reflected to the cell when it's showed again , sine it's cell 2 then

```
let cellModel = arr[1]  // cell 2 of 0 based indexing 
cellModel.someProperty = ///
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I alter the model?